# How Navigate page full loaded then execute?

Tags: c#, webbrowser-control

I am trying running my navigate URL loading complete after starting my code but it's not going.

```
webBrowser1.Navigate("mail.yahoo.com");
// need page load complete then go executing code.
webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("username").SetAttribute("value", "sumon234");
webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("passwd").SetAttribute("value", "stack234");
webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById(".save").InvokeMember("click");
webBrowser1.Navigate("mail.yahoo.com");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    // navigate...
    webBrowser.Navigate(stringUrl);
    // wait for document ready state...
    while (webBrowser.ReadyState != WebBrowserReadyState.Complete)
    {
        Application.DoEvents();
    }
    // do what you need
```